# Which method is used to estimate the power in the outpout of the VarPower() structure in R

Tags: variance, lme4-nlme

I am applying the power of covariate (varPower() in R) variance structure to the data, but I cannot find which method is used to estimate the power in this structure.
If anyone knows, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.